# fstab doesn't mount after boot of a virtual machine

Tags: boot, mount, virtual-machine, fstab, turnkey

I created virtual machine out of [WordPress turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/wordpress) appliance (I believe it's based on Ubuntu) inside Virtual Box. I am able to mount a folder on turnkey from the host (Windows7) manually.

So I added this to the /etc/fstab

`//10.1.1.4/d/data/Dropbox/onlinebackup/projects/newplugin /var/www/wordpress/wp-
content/plugins/newplugin cifs username=user,password=password`

but the mount doesn't work after starting the virtual machine. Interestingly when the machine is up and running I can ssh there and run `mount -a` and the Windows directory is mounted.

Any idea what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Dont really know your OS that well so this is a guess - I'd be looking at when networking starts vs when "mount -a" is called by the boot sequence.  There's usually a pivot/remount of the root device follows by a "mountall" in most builds... The later mountall after networking sometimes is triggered by NFS mount presence or so forth.

Not amazingly helpful and I sure dont know how to debug your boot sequence.  Alternative "bodge" is to put mount -a in your /etc/rc.local (or OS equivalent) which will just get run at the end of all init sequences.

Comment: I was also thinking of adding `mount -a` into rc.local but I find it as a workaround only.

Comment: @iain, ubuntu doesn't actually use the traditional `mountall`.  Its version in upstart runs as a daemon waiting for the underlying devices ( or network ) to come up, then mounts them, after mounting any other mounts it depends on.

Comment: To amplify @iain, since `mount -a` works properly at some time after boot, it is almost certainly a sequencing issue. You might try adding `bootwait` to the fstab options as described in fstab(5).

Comment: @msw: it seems to me that bootwait is not available for me.

Comment: I appreciate the complexity of upstart vs traditional SysVInit.  A little poking leads us to a series of scripts in /etc/init that are called "mountall", the man page for which, and i quote, says "This is a temporary tool until init(8) itself gains the necessary flexibility to perform this processing; you should not rely on its behaviour.".   
   
So, good luck with that, I think I'd just stick to bodging it until "init gets its act together" :P

Answer (score 0):

TurnKey Linux is currently based on Debian (v13.x is based on Debian Wheezy; previous v12.x based on Squeeze; prior to that it was Ubuntu based - v11.x based on Lucid).

I [have read](http://lifeisabug.com/fix-debian-wheezy-mounting-cifs-smb-shares-boot-time/) that editing `/etc/default/rcS` and adding:

```
ASYNCMOUNTNFS=no
```

resolves the issue. However, others have complained that their boot hangs or that their filesystem mounts read-only after that adjustment, so I'm not sure...